# creating mysql tables id best pratice

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am coding a new python (version 3.8.2) project with a mysql(8.0.19) db.
This is the table creation code:

```
    import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    password = "mypassword",
    database = "acme_db"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql_formula = ("CREATE TABLE employee (employee_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
                                        "first_name VARCHAR(255),"
                                        "last_name VARCHAR(255),"
                                        "email VARCHAR(255),"
                                        "phone_nr VARCHAR(255),"
                                        "hire_date DATE,"
                                        "job_id INTEGER,"
                                        "salary NUMERIC(8,2),"
                                        "commission_pct NUMERIC(8,2),"
                                        "manager_id INTEGER,"
                                        "department_id INTEGER)")
mycursor.execute(sql_formula)

mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE jobs (job_id INT, job VARCHAR(255))")

mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE managers (manager_id INT, employee_id INTEGER)")

mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE departments (department_id INT, department_name VARCHAR(255))")
```

The question is, what is the best practice about id?
What I mean is this, employee_id is unique auto increment pk, that I understand, what about the other id's? for tables jobs, managers and departments.
Shouldn't they be also the same as employee_id definition or just INT and I need to take care of the number, that it doesn't repeat itself, and so on?
I did make all id's the same definition but I coudn't insert data to the tables:

```
dptFormula = "INSERT INTO depatments (department_name) VALUES (%s)"
acme_departments = [("Accounting"),("R&D"),("Support")]
mycursor.executemany(dptFormula, acme_departments)
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Daniel/EmployeeProject/employee_mgt/insert_into.py", line 20, in <module>
    mycursor.executemany(dptFormula, acme_departments)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 668, in executemany
    stmt = self._batch_insert(operation, seq_params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 613, in _batch_insert
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: *employee_id is unique auto increment pk* Define it more strict: `employee_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,` (or maybe BIGINT - dependent by total records amount prognosis). *what about the other id's?* Do the same with them.

Comment: `('Accounting')` is just the same as `'Accounting'`. You want to make it a tuple: `('Accounting',)`.

Comment: @Akina I did the way you wrote in all id's and still get the same error: 
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: @DanielBen-Shabtay This is python error, not MySQL. I tell about best practice from the MySQL side only - strictly according to the Subj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using one best practice. Each table has an autoincrementing integer for a primary key, and you named those keys after the tables (`employee_id`, 'job_id`, not just`id`)

Each table has its own sequence of autoincrementing id values.  If you try to look up something in your `employees` table using a `job_id`, you'll get nonsense.  But you can do things like this

```
    SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, j.job
      FROM employee e
      JOIN job h ON e.job_id = j.job_id
```

to exploit the relationship between employee and job. The relationships between rows of tables expressed by  `JOIN job h ON e.job_id = j.job_id` are the reason for the term *relational database management system.*

In a comment, @Akina pointed out you should use this sort of definition for your primary key columns.

```
something_id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

That's good advice.

Comment: I'm curious - why do you recommend using `tbl.tbl_id` over `tbl.id`?  The former seems  like duplication, to me.

Comment: @snakecharmerb . . . (1) Because foreign keys can then generally have the same name as primary keys.  (2) To facilitate the use of `using`.  (3) To prevent ambiguity in query result sets.

Comment: @snakecharmerb *why do you recommend using tbl.tbl_id over tbl.id?* Referencing and referenced fields have the same names in such case. It is more clear. Additionally this allows to use USING clause instead of ON clause.